# XSLT: Difference between using predicates and <xsl:if> statement

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, predicates

I am trying to understand if there is any difference between using predicates and using an `<xsl:if>` ?

From a performance perspective, is the use of a predicate any better? Does predicates also traverse through each node in the xml tree to identify the nodes based on the filter criteria?

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually mean by predicate in this case, as it doesn't really make sense to compare a predicate with `xsl:if`. A predicate is an expression value that is converted to either true or false, and `xsl:if` will be using a predicate in its `test` expression. Thanks.

Comment: Say I want to filter based on Name='John'. I can either do it using predicates,like  [name='John'] or I can do it using <xsl:if test ="name='John'">. In such cases which would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision between placing conditionals within XPath predicates or `xsl:if` (or `xsl:when`) tests is really one of style, not performance.

***Procedural*** code can be written in XSLT using loops and if statements, but to leverage the power of XSLT elegantly, base your XSLT upon its ***declarative*** pattern matching and transformation capabilities.

Instead of thinking ***procedurally*** (*do this; then do that*), think about how to ***declaratively*** express relationship between input XML and output XML via matching and transforming (*match input XML and map to output XML*  This is the purpose of `xs:template`.).  Predicates help you express pattern matching declaratively and therefore are preferred over procedural `xsl:if` statements when using XSLT the way it was designed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT and XQuery use XPath as an expression language, a predicate is part of an XPath expression https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-filter-expression, an `xsl:if` is an instruction of the XSLT language https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-if.

For the example you have mentioned in your comment to Tim I would think that most people prefer the compact XPath syntax approach of selecting and filtering with a predicate, unless you need to output the position of the node with `name = 'John'` in relation to all selected nodes e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="person[name = 'John']"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:for-each>` will output output `1,2,3...` for the number of `person` elements with a `name = 'John'` child element while `<xsl:for-each select="person"><xsl:if test="name = 'John'"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:if></xsl:for-each>` will output the position of each `person` element with a `name = 'John'` child element in the sequence of all `person` elements.

As for performance, I think you would need to check that for a particular case with a particular processor, for a declarative language a processor might choose to rewrite or optimize any code as long as it produces the defined output.